# how not to fill plt polygon patch

Tags: matplotlib, polygon, patch

I used the following code to overlay a polygon on top of an image. But I do not want to fill the polygon. How can I achieve it?

```
polygon = [];
for prop in props:
    polygon.append([int(prop.centroid[1]), int(prop.centroid[0])])

track = optimized_path(polygon)

fig = plt.figure(0)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.imshow(bg[:, :, (2, 1, 0)])
ax.add_patch(plt.Polygon(track, ))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the facecolor and edgecolor properties, which can be abbreviated to fc and ec. Set facecolor to none, and then the edgecolor to what you want the outline to be.

```
plt.Polygon(track, fc='none', ec='orangered')
```

Can also change the linewidth property (lw) to make the line thicker or thinner

```
plt.Polygon(track, fc='none', ec='orangered', lw=3)
```